# Installing fbprophet on colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, facebook-prophet

Hi when I try to intall fbprophet on google colab i get this error anyone knows how to fix it?

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (0.29.30)
Requirement already satisfied: cmdstanpy==0.9.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (0.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan>=2.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: LunarCalendar>=0.0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: convertdate>=2.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: holidays>=0.10.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-git>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.36.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fbprophet) (4.64.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.13 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from convertdate>=2.1.2->fbprophet) (0.5.11)
Requirement already satisfied: hijri-converter in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->fbprophet) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: korean-lunar-calendar in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->fbprophet) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ephem>=3.7.5.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: clikit<0.7,>=0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pysimdjson<4.0,>=3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: httpstan<4.7,>=4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: asynctest==0.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pylev<2.0,>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from clikit<0.7,>=0.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: crashtest<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from clikit<0.7,>=0.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pastel<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from clikit<0.7,>=0.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2.0,>=1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from httpstan<4.7,>=4.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: webargs<9.0,>=8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from httpstan<4.7,>=4.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from httpstan<4.7,>=4.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow<4.0,>=3.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from httpstan<4.7,>=4.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (3.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=17.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from marshmallow<4.0,>=3.10->httpstan<4.7,>=4.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.0->fbprophet) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (2.10)
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: fbprophet
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mghunffz/fbprophet_2d75d382214e4622a66d686904a6dfb7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mghunffz/fbprophet_2d75d382214e4622a66d686904a6dfb7/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-dqpxd5x_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/fbprophet Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm adding some random text so stackoverflow lets me post this question pleas ignore
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this currently i am working on fb-prophet in colab and i used this packages for me it is working smoothly -
This is older version

```
!pip install pystan~=2.14
!pip install fbprophet
```

For latest version just install prophet there is no need for installing pystan -

```
!pip install prophet

import prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in Colab, I solved importing first:

```
import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize
```

then as they mentioned before:

```
!pip install prophet
import prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this when I install this packages in Google Colab:

```
!pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
!pip install convertdate
!pip install lunarcalendar
!pip install holidays==0.10.5
!pip install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "fbprophet" is the old version of the library and "prophet" (already installed in Google Colab) is the new version.

Both are authored by same developers

**Prophet**
https://pypi.org/project/prophet/
Latest version Released: Oct 10, 2023

**fbProphet**
https://pypi.org/project/fbprophet/
Latest version Released: Sep 5, 2020